# Workflow tool for job execution

Tags: exception, workflow, monitoring, business-process-management, alerts

I have a number of ETL jobs that I need to executed in a certain order with certain logic. what is the best workflow /BPM/ orchestration tool suitable for that? I have the following general requirements:

1. Monitoring: To understand the status of a job
2. Exception handling: if a job fails an alert is sent or some sort of action is taken.
3. Alert: an email alert is sent based on certain conditions
4. Approvals: occasionally a coworker of mine needs to approve a job before it execute.

My jobs are written in python and Java, but they can run as executables.

I am considering tools such as ProcessMaker, MuleSoft, etc.

thanks.

Comment: What programming language is this related to? Do you have any diagrams of example workflows you're trying to design to? Those may be helpful for people so they can gauge what choices to offer you. Make this question as explicit as you can, otherwise it might get closed if it's too vague or off-topic!

Comment: good points. I just made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BonitaSoft. It offers BPMN exception handling, an open (source) structure based on REST api's and written in Java.